# NServiceBus: Exception thrown when not using non-XML configuration with Generic host

Tags: nservicebus

I want to use the NServiceBus Generic Host for running my subscriber as a service.  My subscriber uses no-XML configuration, so there is no need for an app.config.  My problem is that since I don't have an app.config, I get this error from the Generic host:

> No configuration file found at: C:\My
>   Dev\NServiceBus2.0.0.1145\samples\PubSub\Subscriber2\bin\Debug\Subscriber2.dll.config

Is there a way to disable to default behavior of the Generic host to NOT search for the .config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no way around this except to host NSB on your own(from the host source):

```
            string endpointConfigurationFile = GetEndpointConfigurationFile(endpointConfigurationType);

            if (!File.Exists(endpointConfigurationFile))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No configuration file found at: " + endpointConfigurationFile);
            }
```

Comment: This is something we should allow for, do you mind adding this to our issue tracker over at github?

Comment: Andreas - all set, issue created: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/issue/11